# See how many time remains for an event using MomentJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, momentjs

I'm trying to determine how much time remains before an event starts. For example, if my event is scheduled for tomorrow at 7:30 pm, I want to print how much time in hours and minutes remain for the event to start.

What I have so far is something like this, where I determine if the event date is after the current date:

```
const { eventDayFinish, eventHourFinish } = this.state;

const currentDate = moment().format();
const dateEvent = moment(`${eventDayFinish} ${eventHourFinish}`, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm a').format();

const after = moment(dateEvent).isAfter(currentDate);
```

Comment: please note: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/.  moment is no longer being supported, and they recommend using a different package

Answer (score 1):

You can use [momentjs difference](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/) to calculate the difference between two dates.

However, [check the status of moment.js project](https://momentjs.com/docs/) - it's not advised to use this library anymore.